# Specify type on SQL Server Computed Column

Tags: sql-server

I have just added a computed column to a table, and it is showing up as an `int` and I'd like to make it a `bit` is this possible? I'm having a hard time finding any info on this. Below is the computed column:

```
IsActive  AS case when DateDecommissioned is null then 0 else 1 end PERSISTED
```

Comment: @Nate - It doesn't have to be persisted to be indexed unless it is imprecise/float or a CLR UDT. An index on a `bit` column won't be used unless heavily skewed. Are you on 2008? You could look into filtered indexes.

Comment: @MartinSmith Good to know. So I can drop the `PERSISTED` and it will not impact index performance?

Comment: @Nate - dropping `PERSISTED` just means that it won't take up space in the data page. Doesn't affect any other indexes that use it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be able to `CAST` to  your preferred data type inside the `CASE`:

`...IS NULL THEN CAST(0 as BIT) ELSE CAST(1 as BIT) END`

Answer (score 5):

Or slightly simpler...

```
IsActive AS CONVERT(BIT, CASE ... END) PERSISTED
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this:

```
ALTER TABLE dbo.MyTablr
ADD  DateDecommissioned AS (cast(Value1 AS bit) * cast(Value2 AS bit)) PERSISTED
```

This way you can determine the Data Type on the fly while you create the computed column